# Using a Loop in PHP to output the month-to-month interest that the user earns based on the principal and interest rate

Tags: php, html

I am attempting to use a loop to calculate the month to month interest rate using PHP. I get an output but the number just repeats itself and the month is not output-ed either. How do I output the month, the interest earned that month, and the new principal balance?

HTML

```
<form action='displayInterest.php' method ='POST'>
    <p>Principal
        <input type = 'text' name ='principal' maxlength='20'/>
    </p>
    <p>Interest Rate
        <input type='text' name='interestRate' maxlength = '20'/>
    </p>
    <p>Term
        <input type='text' name='term' maxlength='20'/>
    </p>
    <input type='submit' value='Calculate Interest'/>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $principal = $_REQUEST['principal'];
    $interestRate = $_REQUEST['interestRate'];
    $term = $_REQUEST['term'];

    $MIR = $interestRate / 12;
    $MI = $principal / $MIR;
    $MB = $principal + $MI;

    $month = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September','October', 'November', 'December');

    for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++){    
        $MI += $month[0];
        echo($MI);
        echo('</br>');
    }    
?>
```

Comment: `$MI` is a string, don't use `+` on it. You also don't appear to be using `$term` Although you probably don't want the `.=` either since it will be appending.

Comment: For the month problem, you should try $MI = $month[$i]

Comment: $MI += $month[$i] is what you need in your loop.

Comment: what is your interest quotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the interest rate and divide by 100 (outside of loop to avoid calculating every single time).

Then you run the loop for the number of terms, assuming your term is in months
:

```
<?php
    $principal = $_REQUEST['principal'];
    $interestRate = $_REQUEST['interestRate'] / 100;
    $term = $_REQUEST['term'];

    $month = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September','October', 'November', 'December');

    $time = 1 / 12;     // Getting the "t" for the formula

    for ($i = 0; $i < $term; $i++) { // Run the loop for the number of terms
        $total = $principal * $interestRate * $time;    // Total is interest formula (P * r * t)
        $principal += $total;                           // Add total to principal to calculate for next month
        echo "<b>" . $month[$i] . "</b>: Interest: " . $total . ", Principal: " . $principal . "<br/>";      // Output month, interest earned, and new principal
    }
?>
```

My output for a principal of `10000`, interest of `5`, and term of `5` is:

```
January: Interest: 41.666666666667, Principal: 10041.666666667
February: Interest: 41.840277777778, Principal: 10083.506944444
March: Interest: 42.014612268519, Principal: 10125.521556713
April: Interest: 42.189673152971, Principal: 10167.711229866
May: Interest: 42.365463457775, Principal: 10210.076693324
```

You can than format the output however you want.

Answer (score 0):

You increment the month wrong, and thus, it appears to break the rest of your loop. The following should be what you need:

```
$MIR = $interestRate / 12;
$MI = $principal / $MIR;
$MB = $principal + $MI;

$month = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September','October', 'November', 'December');

for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++){    
    $MI = $month[$i];
    echo $MI .'<br>';
}
```

Note that the $MI variable is being overwritten in the loop, I suggest changing that to something different, or simply outputting the $month like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++){
    echo $month[$i] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: This still does not show the interest earned month to month.

Comment: That's true, I'm imagining the OP needs to possibly have 12 different input fields then?

Comment: @Adam; should I add a select list in order to give the user the month to choose from?

Comment: @WCA, I presume so, though I may be slightly misunderstanding what you want for the final output. My answer above only outputs the $month's array value. It doesn't take into account any sort of maths.

Comment: @Adam Thank you Adam, I am going to add a select list for better usability

Answer (score 0):

If you only need interest value and month try this code inside your loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $rate = ($principal * $interestRate) / 100;
    echo $month[$i] . " => " . $rate;
    $principal += $rate;
    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem right at all.. In my calculations of `10000` principal, `5%` interest, and `1` term it SHOULD be `$41.67`, but your code gives `$5`.

Comment: i calculate compound interest formula. you can change it as your requirement. if your principal =10000 and rate of interest 5% then it will bee 500 for 1st month then 550 for 2nd and so on...

Comment: That still doesn't seem right. Should also show the new principal as per OP's question: `How do I output the month, the interest earned that month, and the new principal balance?`